# Can we construct $142$ degrees and $172$ degrees by using only straightedge and compass?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, angle, geometric-construction

> Can we construct $142$ degrees and $172$ degrees by using only straightedge and compass?

I already tried rewrite $142$ to get some angles that can be constructed , such as $90$,$45$,$60$,$30$,$15$,$12$ and all multiples of these numbers. But, I still can't construct it. Any hints? Thank you.

Comment: No. Since angles can be added, subtracted, and halved, and all multiples of $3^\circ$ are constructible, if $142^\circ$ were constructible, then also $$142^\circ-47*3^\circ=1^\circ$$ and thus $140^\circ$ (for example) would be constructible. But we know that the regular $9$-gon is not constructible.

Comment: thank you very much, @mr_e_man

Comment: @mr_e_man You should make this an answer.